# Build error on Vercel after Typescript file in Next.JS renamed

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vercel

I have time options that I export to specific files named TimeOptions where I have `Intl.DateFormat` code like this
[image]

When I rename the file from `TimeOptions` to `timeOptions`, Vercel told that `Type error: Cannot find module '../utils/timeOptions' or its corresponding type declarations.` on build.

[image]

When I built it locally with `next build`, the results looks fine and no error.

Do you know what's happened? I have tried to setup `tsconfig.js` as mentioned in other threads but nothing seems to work on Vercel.

Here I attach the tsconfig file.
[image]

Thank you very much for your kind help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's caused by git not being case sensitive on file naming and not picking up your change.

You can fix it like this:

```
mv timeOptions.ts temp.ts
git add -A
git commit -m "renaming..."
mv temp.ts TimeOptions.ts
git add -A
git commit --amend -m "Rename timeOptions.ts to TimeOptions.ts"
```

Answer (score 2):

Its true, this is because `git` by default is case insensitive for filenames. To fix this, go to your `git config` and change `ignorecase = false` param. Or run the command `git config core.ignorecase false`